# Flash 3d Blurred text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I have one of the most common issues that people face when they use transformations in the 3d space. The problem is that the content that is being transformed in 3d gets blurry.

Now to fix this there is one famous solution.

i.e assuming the object is say *mc*.

```
mc.transform.matrix3d = null;
```

Once the animation ends you could set the movieclip's 3d matrix to null. This fixes the problem but there is a definite jerking you see when the animation completes and the matrix3d is nullified.

One of the solutions defined in flashandmath is

http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/blursol/index.html

But this is not working fine for me.

If someone has a better solution that works across the board ( without any jerks! ) please let the community know !

Comment: Do you see the "jerk" on the example on the second page there: http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/blursol/blursol2.html or is it just when you try to apply this to your code, how is it not working for you (compile errors, run-time errors, or just doesn't act like the example).

Comment: When I apply it to my code it just doesnt work like the example. Maybe perhaps because I have text in my frame.

Comment: Hi Ganaraj, can you show the code for text if it is dynamically created. Do you use maybe the antialiasing options? I've found that when text is using the AdvancedAntiAlias with pixel snapping than you can notice "jerking" when animates because the text renderer snaps to the nearest pixel.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I tried setting the text to NORMAL antialias but still the problem persisted. This is not just for the text though, the whole frame which is rotated gets that jerk reset.

Comment: Hi Ganraj, can you post a link to a sample that will depict the problem?

Comment: Try setting the scaleX of your content to .99

Answer (score 2):

Without an actual source code it's hard to pinpoint the exact cause for it, but in general, all blurring in Flash happens due to either the resampling of the image (compensating smoothness/sharpness when showing the image in size different than its original size) or due to non-integer values of the object's coordinates.

To fix this, you usually have to make sure that all your objects have integer (non-floating point) coordinates (especially the text objects) and make sure you apply that scaling correction fix that you linked to, to prevent the resampling of the 3d objects, and you should be good to go.